# yii2 can not read json file into backend/web folder

Tags: json, yii2

I have js file in **backend/web/js/my.js**

```
var conf = function() {
  return ('../conf.json');
}
```

But can not read conf.json file. I got 403 error. What is the problem ?

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
var conf = function() {
   return ('../js/conf.json');
}
```

or build the proper url using urlHelper

```
<?= 'var url_base = "' . \yii\helpers\Url::base() .'";'; ?>
var conf = function() {
   return ( url_base + '/js/conf.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add some row in .htacces file into the root

```
#if files in the root
RewriteRule conf.php conf.php [L]
#or
RewriteRule conf.json conf.json [L]

#if files in the directory into the root
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ js/$1 [L]
#or images directory
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
```